# How to insert table cells starting from the right-most end/column of the table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, tablecell

I'm working on a table and adding cells to the table in a snake like fashion.

So you can imagine, for row 1: I want to have a function that adds table cells from the left-most column to right-most column

Then for row 2: I want to have a function that adds table cells from the right most column to the left-most column.

Using this code from w3schools accomplishes the movement from left to right...

```
function myFunction() {
  var row = document.getElementById("myRow");
  var x = row.insertCell(-1);
  x.innerHTML = "New cell";
}
```

[adding cells from left to right](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tr_insertcell2)

However, I need help going from right to left. I'm aware of this:

```
row.insertCell(0)
```

but this adds cells to the left of the starting cell and pushes them to the right. **I would like to start at the right-most column, and add cells 1, by 1 (to the left of last one added) until the left-most column of the table is reached**. Think of a fantasy football draft board, and going in a snake like fashion across the table. From left to right on the 1st row, right to left on the 2nd row, left to right on the 3rd, right to left on the 4th, etc...Any ideas?

Comment: do you want this: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/kphe5fbL/14/

Comment: The [DOM Core *insertBefore* method](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727) should suit: `row.insertBefore(newCell, row.firstChild)`. Each newly inserted cell will become the first child.

Comment: @eugen sunic - that is exactly what I'm looking for, but let me double check when I get back to my laptop. I'm checking this on my iPhone right now

Comment: @Seeeyonnn I've included the link in my post below it would be nice if you accepted is as an answer so that someone else having the same/similar issue can refer  to it

Answer (score 1):

A CSS solution is likely your best bet, a script solution is a bit clunky.

You can fill the row with a spacer cell that has a cellspan of the number of cells in the row. Then each time you append a cell after it, reduce it's cellspan by 1. Finally, remove the spacer.

The following is an example implementation, adding cells from right to left. You should be able to adapt the algorithm to what you need, I hope the comments are sufficient. There's probably a better way to do it.

Once it fills the row, it deletes it ready to start again…

I've used a *data-** attribute to identify the spacer, but you could use a class or even ID.

```js
function doCellThing() {
  var table = document.querySelector('table');
  var numCells = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  var spacer, cell, i;

  // Grab second row if there is one, or create a new one
  var row = table.rows[1] || table.insertRow();

  // Get the first cell in the row
  cell = row.cells[0];

  // If it's not a spacer cell, remove the row
  if (cell && !cell.hasAttribute('data-span')) {
    table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
    return;

  // Otherwise, it's a spacer
  } else {
    spacer = cell
  }

  // If there are no cells, insert a spacer cell
  if (!spacer) {
    spacer = row.insertCell();
    spacer.colSpan = numCells;
    spacer.setAttribute('data-span','span');
  }

  // If spacer width is 1, remove it. Otherwise, 
  // reduce span by 1
  if (spacer.colSpan == 1) {
    row.deleteCell(0);
    spacer = null;

  } else {
    spacer.colSpan = spacer.colSpan - 1;
  } 

  // Insert a new cell to the left of previous cells
  cell = row.insertCell(spacer? 1 : 0)
  cell.innerHTML = numCells - row.cells.length + (spacer? 1 : 0);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="doCellThing()">Do cell thing</button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>0<th>1<th>2<th>3
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you want the following with leaving your `row.inserCell(-1)`; just add a new td element with a float attribute like this:

```
td{float:right;}
```

Or if you want to start from the right corner to the and go to the left you can then use this:

```
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    float:right;
}
```

Link to OP solution :  https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/kphe5fbL/14/

Comment: Upon first glance I thought this worked, but this will change the entire table to go from right to left. I'm trying to get the first row to go from left to right and then the 2nd row to go from right to left. Any ideas beyond changing all td's to float right?